# using hashMap to assign val to char

Tags: java, methods, hashmap, char

I am trying to assign integer values to upper case letters using `HashMap`.
I am able to assign one value to one character; however, I need to store each value to specific character [keep in mind both the letter and the integer value are specified by the user]. This is where I need help.

I need to store the user defined integer value into the user defined character and for every letter, IF not assigned a integer value, THEN it retains its integer value of it's position in the alphabet. I can not figure out how to loop and do this using a `HashMap` object

Currently I'm storing the int value in the char as >>> `mapObj.put(ch,intValue);`

and calling as >> `int getValue = mapObj.get(ch);`

but it only calls the value I want to call both letter and the value together if it is possible.

I have tried for looping it and while looping it, neither of which I can get the logic correct.

```
Map<Character, Integer> mapObj = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = " ";
char ch = ' ';
int startIndex;
int strLength;
int value = 0;
String strValue = " ";
while(kbd.hasNext())
{
    str = kbd.nextLine();
    if(str.equals("QUIT"))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        ch = str.charAt(0);
        startIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ")+1;
        StringLength = str.length();
        strValue = str.substring(startIndex,StringLength);
        value = Integer.parseInt(strValue);

        System.out.println(""+strValue);
        tempIndex.put(ch,value);
        int VarValue = tempIndex.get(ch);
        System.out.println(ch+" = "+VarValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe an obvious answer it what I need lol. I have not tried too too much just can not figure out the logic of it I guess is the best way to sum my attempts of forming a loop

Comment: Please post the code you do have. Also, have you considered using a `Character` key and a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) value?

Comment: No Idea what either of those two are, I will post my code.

Comment: No idea on what you are trying to say: `but it only calls the value I want to call both letter and the value together if it is possible`.  What does this mean?   And you said `I have tried for looping it and while looping it, neither of which I can get the logic correct.` What are you looping then? Cannot understand what you are trying to say here again...  What is your question in fact? You have problem getting input from user? Or some problem when you iterate through the map?

Comment: okay so my problem is I can do it once store everything ONCE, BUT i need to do it 26 times and IF the user does not assign a int value to a letter it needs to retain its alphabetical value (i.e. b=2)

Comment: "you can do it once" -> That's a problem?  Can you be more precise and clear on what problem you are facing?

Comment: the user enters the string "c =45" I than store the int value of 45 into char c, if the user does not enter any other arguments each char in the alphabet should retain a its position represented as a integer (i.e z=26)

Comment: so what is your problem?  You don't know how to store the thing in a Map? (But you have shown us you do), you don't know how to get user input (but your code seems valid to me)?  Anyway, consider Bret's answer, I think you are making things unnecessary messy now

Comment: @brets answer is just a letter count

Comment: Bret's answer is about how you store value against alphabet.  It is not necessary to be letter count.  It proved that you haven't actually tried to read other people's answer carefully.  And you still have not tell us what is your problem.  Can you try to revise your question to make sure what you wrote make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a `Map<Character, Integer>` and populating it with **{`A`-`Z`}** and **{`1`-`26`}**

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i + 'A' <= 'Z'; i++) {
    char key = (char) ('A' + i);
    int defaultValue = i + 1;
    map.put(key, defaultValue);
}
```

If we were to now run `System.out.println(map);` we would see

> {A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4, E=5, F=6, G=7, H=8, I=9, J=10, K=11, L=12, M=13, N=14, O=15, P=16, Q=17, R=18, S=19, T=20, U=21, V=22, W=23, X=24, Y=25, Z=26}

which means the `map` is now **initialized**. Next, I would use `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` and a more generic `Scanner` name. What if you wanted to use a `Scanner` that was backed by a file? I'd use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to separate the input into tokens. Something like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    if ("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
        break;
    }
    if (!line.isEmpty()) {
        String[] arr = line.toUpperCase().split("\\s+");
        char ch = arr[0].charAt(0);
        int val = Integer.parseInt(arr[arr.length - 1]);
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
            map.put(ch, val);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(map); // <-- output after getting all of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you code (for your homework), there are two different cases going on here (if I understand your question correctly):

1. The char c has an integer assigned -> return the assigned integer
2. The char c does *not* have an integer - return c's alphabetic position

This can be achieved by:

1. First populate a map with letters A-Z assigned to integers 1-26 - this will step up the "nth letter" mappings
2. Have the user specify custom assignments that overwrite assignments from step 1 (calling `map.put()` again overwrites)

Now you have a map that has what you want.

Comment: would it look something like `Map<Character, Integer> mapObj = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(26,A-Z); ?`

Comment: would `A-Z` be the correct way to code it? that is what I'm confused about when instantiating the object

Answer (score 0):

If there are ever only going to be 26 values that you want to store in your map, why not have a bit of mechanical sympathy for the poor old microprocessor and just use an array?

For example, HashMap implementation...

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapVsArray1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "The quick lazy fox forgets how to type the sentance so that each letter appears only once and something to do with jumping over something";

        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int k = 0; k < input.length(); k++) {
            char key = Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(k));

            if (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z') {
                Integer currentCount = map.get(key);

                if (currentCount == null) {
                    currentCount = 0;
                }

                currentCount++;
                map.put(key, currentCount);
            }
        }

        // Output results (rely on HashMap's toString)...
        System.out.println(map);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
{D=2, E=14, F=2, G=4, A=7, C=4, L=3, M=3, N=8, O=12, H=8, I=5, J=1, K=1, U=2, T=14, W=2, V=1, Q=1, P=4, S=6, R=4, Y=3, X=1, Z=1}
```

Whereas using arrays...

```
package stackoverflow;


public class MapVsArray2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "The quick lazy fox forgets how to type the sentance so that each letter appears only once and something to do with jumping over something";

        int[] counts = new int[26];

        for (int k = 0; k < input.length(); k++) {
            char key = Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(k));

            if (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z') {
                counts[key - 'A']++;
            }
        }

        // Output results...
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            char letter = (char) ('A' + i);
            System.out.print(letter + "=" + counts[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Output...

```
A=7 B=0 C=4 D=2 E=14 F=2 G=4 H=8 I=5 J=1 K=1 L=3 M=3 N=8 O=12 P=4 Q=1 R=4 S=6 T=14 U=2 V=1 W=2 X=1 Y=3 Z=1
```

Basically, the array solution is less computationally expensive.

Comment: B's out put should be according to its alphabetical order which is 1 and 0. so this would not work.

Comment: Re-read what the program is suppose to do. this is just a letter count.

Comment: @Lex sorry, I was just on a "Why use hashmaps to just store 26 things" one... I'll delete this post soon if it is not deemed relevant (downvote if necessary... :( )

Answer (score 0):

Have read your question over ten times but still don't understand what you are asking.  You said

> I have tried for looping it and while looping it, neither of which I can get the logic correct.

I bet you are asking for way to iterate through entries in a `Map` right? (I cannot see the point you are quoting your irrelevant code anyway...)

If it is the case, here is how we normally do:

```
Map<Foo, Bar> myMap = ....;

for (Map.Entry<Foo,Bar> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key is a Foo, which is " + entry.getKey());
    System.out.println("value is a Bar which is " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: what is entry and entrySet?

Comment: I think what you need is a beginner book of Java and read through it and make sure you understand the basics.  It is hard to communicate if you can't even understand `entry` is a variable name, and `entrySet()` is a method of `Map` (for which you can read Javadoc to understand what it does)